# Should I add 129 columns to my main table or create a new table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I need to add fields to a table that has some of the highest amount of traffic on it. It is constantly being read and being written to fairly often. I am all for data normalization and minimizing data redundancy, so my initial instinct is to add these fields to the main table. However, it would be adding 129 columns. Here is an example:

```
field:   AssemblyFunctionGroup      AssemblyActionState     AssemblyFunctionName 
         (nvarchar(50);null)        (tinyint;null/1/0)      (nvarchar(75);null)
example: 'Assembly'                 1                       'Start Assembly'
```

The idea is that as a job progresses, it passes through stages and each stage has a start/stop pairing. For example, one stage is called 'Assembly'. When this is started, the `ActionState` field goes from `NULL` to `1` and the `FunctionName` goes from `NULL` to 'Start Assembly'. When this stage is done, the `ActionState` becomes `0` and the `FunctionName` becomes 'Stop Assembly'.

**Visualization of how the row will progress:**

```
(no row)
'Assembly'                 1                       'Start Assembly'
'Assembly'                 0                       'Stop Assembly'
```

There are 43 stages and for each one I'm planning on creating a `FunctionGroup`, `ActionState`, and `FunctionName` field, so 43 x 3 = 129. Right now the table already has 41 columns and thankfully only has 1 small trigger. Total column count would therefore be 170 if I add these.

According to what I've seen online, SQL Server can handle up to 1024 columns in one table. This is great, but I'm wondering if performance will take such a hit that it would be better to create a separate table to house the new columns. This would get rid of that fear for me but then it would mean me creating data redundancy because I would need to add the PK of the main table into this secondary table. How should I resolve this?

**Update:** I forgot to mention that some of these stages can happen in parallel. For example, the LocationStage might be in 'Enter Room 1' and inside this room we might update the AssemblyStage to be 'Start Assembly'. They don't all happen in series so I can't add just 1 current stage column to my main table.

Comment: [Swart’s Ten Percent Rule](https://michaeljswart.com/2013/05/swarts-ten-percent-rule/)

Comment: @ErikDarling He doesn't really give a reason for the 10% other than `I get the feeling that if you need over 10% of what Microsoft restricts you to, then you’re probably doing it wrong.`

Answer (score 3):

> The idea is that as a job progresses, it passes through stages and each stage has a start/stop pairing.

The number and names of stages is data, not schema.  Modeling this as schema instead of data makes you have too many columns.  What if there were 1000 different stages? 10,000?

The job should have at most the current stage and, and the history of previous stages (and perhaps the schedule for future stages) should be in a separate table, something like

```
create table Stages
(
  Stage varchar(20) primary key
)

create table Jobs
(
  Id int identity primary key, 
  CurrentStage varchar(20) references Stages, 
  CurrentStageBegin datetime2(0)
)

create table JobStageHistory
(
  JobId int not null references Jobs,
  JobStageHistoryId int identity not null,
  Stage varchar(20) references Stages,
  StageBegin datetime2(0),
  StageEnd datetime2(0),
  primary key (JobId, JobStageHistoryId)
)
```

Comment: I see now that I forgot to mention a crucial point in my question - these stages can happen in parallel. For example, the LocationStage can be 'Enter Room 1' and then inside this room the AssemblyStage can be 'Start Assembly'. So we can't just have 1 column in the Jobs table with the current stage.

Comment: Then remove that column, and record all running stages in the JobStageHistoryTable.  The "current stage" is only there for convenience, like an order total, where the order line items are the authoritative source of the truth.

Comment: We already have a JobStageHistory table, but if I want the current state for all stages for a large range of jobs, this query takes a long time. So I figured it might be faster to just set these properties on the Jobs table and then they would just be there with no need for an intense query. For reference, I'm using a view to get the current state for a stage for all jobs in the Jobs table. I haven't finished adding all the stages to it yet which is why I was considering just adding the stages to the row in the Jobs table.

Comment: I wouldn't change the schema to improve the performance of a reporting query.  You can always introduce an indexed view or batch job to generate an optimal data structure for reporting.

Comment: "*if I want the current state for all stages for a large range of jobs, this query takes a long time. So I figured it might be faster to just set these properties on the Jobs table*" - Sounds like denormalization-ish, and to David's point not worth changing the schema over. Having the added details you've been providing along the way, all upfront, would've been good to know. Performance issues are likely related to your query and / or index structure, and can be solved separately if that was the question you wanted to focus on.

Answer (score 1):

### First Thoughts

It's hard to visualize your schema without seeing your current table definition and your proposed new definition. But it sounds like these new fields aren't core properties of the original object of your table, rather they seem to describe different states that the object can be in during its lifetime. So from a logical design perspective alone, it sounds to me like they should be a separate table, akin to at the application layer it would probably be a separate class.

### What Is Normalization

> I am all for data normalization and minimizing data redundancy, so my initial instinct is to add these fields to the main table

This is not normalization (and for a lot of use cases, is the opposite of normalization). See below for why.

> it would be better to create a separate table to house the new columns...but then it would mean me creating data redundancy because I would need to add the PK of the main table into this secondary table.

Data normalization's purpose is to improve data integrity by eliminating redundancy on the **dependency columns** from *within a single table*. Denormalized data will repeat the same **non-key column** values inside the same table.

Normalization of that data results in a distinct set of records for that data in its own table, with a key reference from the original table. In other words, it is normal with normalization, to store the value of keys across multiple tables - this is not data redundancy at the cost of data integrity. That is a normal relational implementation. This is also why it's important to choose primary keys that are immutable, and typically decoupled from meaning in their value. With a guaranteed lack of change to the primary key, there is zero risk of data integrity issues relating to using it as a foreign key from other tables.

### How Your Data Relates

Your proposed new columns sound like they'll have a *one-to-one* relationship with the original table. If that's so, it won't necessarily denormalize your data by storing it in the original table. But it's even simpler if you were to use a separate table to manage that data then.

For data attributes that are *one-to-many* (or even *many-to-many*), when they are stored directly in the *one* side table of the relationship is when the data becomes denormalized at the risk of data integrity. This is because one of those attributes values are liable to change, and there will be many instances of that value stored in the table. So the risk comes at ensuring all instances of the value are updated correctly and completely.

In such cases, that's where it's better to use a separate table to normalize those fields, so that they only exist as a single instance, and their primary key is the only thing repeated as a foreign key in the original table. Again, because well defined primary keys should be immutable. Now should anything relating to those (non-key) data attributes need to change, only a single instance needs to be updated in the new table.

### Final Thoughts

- Design tables logically to how the actual objects are shaped in concrete form (usually this is a good start design)
- It's *normal* to repeat foreign key values inside a table (or across multiple tables), this is a relational database after all
- Primary keys should be designed to be immutable, so there is no data integrity risk with their referencing foreign keys
- Normalization usually results in multiple tables with foreign keys, at the benefit of reducing redundant data attributes to a distinct set of rows (tuples)
- [Swart's Ten Percent Rule](https://michaeljswart.com/2013/05/swarts-ten-percent-rule/) that Erik mentioned is a good guideline
- By not making your original table too wide with additional meta-data, the performance and maintenance of that table will be better (especially if you have use cases where you only need to consume that object's core properties, and don't always need the additional state-based fields)